# SQL search using PHP arrays

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to search multiple fields in a MySQL database with a PHP array.

For example, search fields like place_name, admin_name1, and admin_name2 using an array of `["Cambridge","Massachusetts","US"]` with using the wildcard `%`

Below is the exact structure of database
[image: ]]]

Comment: how do you want to search? clarify with more example.

Comment: to be exact I'm trying to implement a php in a such way that it outputs a JSON array of objects using `header("Content-type: application/json");
    print(json_encode($places, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));`, each of which represents a row from places that somehow matches the value of parameters passed such as: `["Cambridge", "Massachusetts", "US"]` `["Cambridge", "Massachusetts"]` `["Cambridge","MA"]` `["02138"]`

Answer (score 1):

Imagining your **array index names** are the same as your **table column names**:

```
$query = "select * from tableName";
$arrCount = count($arrName);
$i=1;
if($arrCount) > 0){
    $query .= " where";
    foreach($arrName as $key->$val){
        $query .= $key." LIKE '%".$val."%'";
        if($i <= $arrCount)
            $query .= " AND";
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Then run the query!

Comment: Querying data and then filtering it in code is bad practice. Do it directly in the query instead.

Comment: Actually in this approach the data is queried after the query is structured!'

Comment: I was mistaken, you are right. But now you are appending plain text to an SQL query. This is bad practice due to the peril of SQL-injection. It'd be better to use prepared statements instead.

Comment: @klaar That would be the best practice for the values. There's not much that can be done with the keys however.

Comment: `$query .= $key." LIKE %".$val."%";` you need to put quotation marks before and after `%` symbol. Otherwise this will end up with error.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = ["Cambridge","Massachusetts","US"];
$list = implode(",", $array);
```

Then select:

```
... WHERE place_name IN($list) OR admin_name1 IN($list) OR admin_name2 IN($list)
```

Comment: `$list = implode(",", $geo);`
`$places = query("SELECT * FROM places WHERE place_name IN($list) OR admin_name1 IN($list) OR admin_name2 IN($list)");`

Comment: Can you give me full error, i haven't find issue in this code yet.

Comment: `Fatal error: Unknown column 'Cambridge' in 'where clause'` for an array of `[ "Cambridge", "Massachusetts" ]`

Comment: Ok, please try this:
$list = implode(' "," ', $geo); $list = $list = ' " '.$list.' " ';

Comment: (please remove the space character between quotes)

Comment: I was able to get the expected results with the below code but they aren't in the order of I was looking for. For instance I want most relevant row to be on top - `"place_name": "Cambridge",  "admin_name1": "Massachusetts"` with a input of ["Cambridge", "Massachusetts"] instead I get `["place_name": "Cambridge",  "admin_name1": "Iowa"]` followed by other matches.

Comment: `$query = "SELECT * FROM places WHERE";
    foreach ($geo as $index => $parameter) 
    {
        print("$parameter\n");
        if ($index > 0)
            $query .= " AND ";
        $query .= " place_name LIKE '$parameter%' OR admin_name1 LIKE '$parameter%'";
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$fields =  array("place_name", "admin_name1",  "admin_name2");
$kwd    =  array("Cambridge","Massachusetts","US");

$condition  =  array();
$n = 0;
foreach($fields as $field){
    $condition[]  .=   $field." LIKE '%".$kwd[$n]."%'";
    $n++;
}
$condition  =   implode(" AND ", $condition);
echo $qry = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE ( ".$condition." )";
```

Comment: You're relying on `$n` having the correct index for an array unrelated to `$fields`. These assumptions are usually where errors are born.

Comment: assumption since the OP not responding.